# When do you get Mouse.getstate().X or Y as negative?

Tags: c#, xna, mouse

I am creating a game in which I use a function:

```
int x()
{
    int px = 100;
    int pxend = 128;
    int xx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        l = Mouse.GetState().X;
        if (l > px && l < pxend)
        {
            xx = px;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            px += 128;
            pxend += 128;
        }
    }
    return xx;
}

int y()
{
    int px = 100;
    int pxend = 128;
    int xx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        l = Mouse.GetState().X;
        if (l > px && l < pxend)
        {
            xx = px;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            px += 128;
            pxend += 128;
        }
    }
    return xx;
}
```

But when I debug I get a `l` value as negative even though the debug is initiate after a click on the `GameWindow` screen. Sometimes it works fine, sometimes does not. I don't know why it gives me negative value. And when I use them with my `Rectangle` I get `Rectangle.X` and `Rectangle.Y` as 0.

Comment: "And when I use them with my Rectangle.." which Rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mousestate.x.aspx):

> If the mouse is to the left of the client area (the inside portion of
>   the game window, excluding the borders), the returned coordinate is
>   negative. If the mouse is to the right of the client area, the
>   returned coordinate is greater than the window's client area width.

This is more of a comment than an answer (I don't have enough reputation to comment), but I've only seen this happen if the mouse is outside of the window... I would recommend taking that `GetState()` call out of the for loop and just calling it once outside the loop - that's the only thing that sticks out to me. You say sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, is this totally random or is it on the first time you hit the `GetState()` call?